# Line renderer not working as expected?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using line renderer to create fruit ninja style swipe effect. But it is not working.Line was supposed to follow the mouse pos but it is not doing so Here is the code. Please help me to solve this. And this script is attached to gameobject line(empty) at position of (0,0,1).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LineFOllow : MonoBehaviour {
    int vertexcount =0;
    bool mousedown = false;
    private LineRenderer line;

    void Start () {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) // gets called when mouse is clicked
        {
            mousedown = true;
        }

        if (mousedown)
        { 
            Debug.Log("called");
            line.positionCount = vertexcount+1;
            Vector3 mousepos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

            line.SetPosition(vertexcount, mousepos);
            vertexcount++;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))// gets called when mouse is released
        {
            vertexcount = 0;
            line.positionCount = 0;
            mousedown = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working; are we talking about an error, or not the desired effect?

Comment: @Jereon desired effect. I told it was to go like fruit ninja

Comment: Check The vector3.Z of the points in the line if they are able to be viewed by camera.

Comment: @Jeroen I tried that not working

Comment: Does the linerender have Use World Space enabled and is it's gameobject a child of something?

Comment: @Jereon world space is disabled and no child

Comment: I think you are putting worldspace coordinates in and it is using local coordinates. try enabling it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151196/discussion-between-jeroen-de-clercq-and-samrat-luitel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable worldspace coordinates for linerender.

Comment: That does nothing

Comment: Then there is an additional problem because that is surely a problem by itself. Are you seeing any lines at all?

Comment: yes I see the line when I manually change the position of it but code does not do it

Answer (score 0):

In your case I think is better to use a [TrailRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TrailRenderer.html).

```
private TrailRenderer trail;
public float depth;
void Start()
{
    depth = 10;
    trail = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
}       
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {                      
        Vector3 mousepos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, depth);
        Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousepos);
        trail.transform.position = position;
    }
}
```

Change the `Time`, `MinVertexDistance` (and other) properties on your `TrailRenderer` component to get the desired effect.